# synchronous write on a file different exceptions and access denied

Tags: c#, uwp, synchronization, async-await, file-writing

i need to synchronous write on a file, i know that there are methods to do that async but thats not my case.

after navigate from an other page.xml i come to my main page and in the onnavigated method i need to write in a file.txt a text that i takes from the previous page.
(that's how i thought to save a data from a first open of the app and every time the app will open it will load these data to not make tutorial anymore)

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
Regione = e.Parameter as regione;
string ciccio = "" + Regione2.RegNome.ToString() + "," + Regione2.RegLat.ToString() + "," + Regione2.regLon.ToString();
            //File.WriteAllText("Data/data1.txt", ciccio);
            File.WriteAllText("C:/Users/giuli/Documents/Source/xxx/XXX/XXX/Data/data1.txt", ciccio);
 }
```

and if i try with the `File.WriteAllText("C:/Users/giuli/Documents/Source/xxx/XXX/XXX/Data/data1.txt", ciccio);`
i get an exception that tell me that i cannot use sync method:
"Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run."

ok but i need to, and i tried with `File.WriteAllText("Data/data1.txt", ciccio);`
and i get an
System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
access to the path denied

and if i try with some async method

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            StorageFile File2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Data/data1.txt"));
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(File2, ciccio1);
```

i get an
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Accesso negato

i created the file data.txt via visual studio, it's not open on VS and i think noone know that that file exist rather than VS.

How can i finally write on that file ?

Thanks .)

"the read sync and async method work perfect so it's not a problem about the path 
`Regione.RegNome = File.ReadAllText("Data/data1.txt");`"

Answer (score 2):

Other than the error saying not to call synchronous API from the UI thread none of the other errors you have are related to the API being synchronous or asynchronous. They all look like legitimate errors because the app doesn't have access to write to the locations it attempts to write to.

Use [ApplicationData.RoamingSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_RoamingSettings) to store your seen-the-tutorial flag. You don't need to manage this yourself in a file. See [Store and retrieve app settings and data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) for details.

The UnauthorizedAccessException on ms-appx:///Data/data1.txt is because an app's install location is read only. Sync vs. async isn't relevant here: reading but not writing from this location is expected to work. The install location is also shared between users, so even if the app could write here it wouldn't be a good place for user-specific data like a seen-the-tutorial flag. If you want to store this in a writable user-specific file then use ApplicationData.LocalFolder or RoamingFolder as described in [Store and retrieve app settings and data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data)

The app doesn't have direct access to the Documents folder. With appropriate capabilities it can get brokered access to that folder via the StorageFile class, but the app won't have direct access using System.IO.File.

Comment: so everytime i wanna write something on a file i had to delete and replace the file that i have? because in your link say that i've to use to write in a file the same thing that i've done with "await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile); and i takes the same access error(if i try to write on my existing file), but if i createfileasync and replacing that one which is already existing it allows me to write on it. why is so difficult?! i just wanna write a simple couple of words in a txt...